# I can't get the second golem to move at Drangleic Castle

Tags: dark-souls-2

I've got the first golem to move but the second won't I've tried for hours and I can't get it to move. And I've got over a million souls, and I've lit the 4 primal bonfires.

Comment: It is a puzzle. Have you understood how you've got the first golem to move? Also it is not clear which golem you are talking about.

Comment: @klm123 sure, it is a puzzle, "find the key that fits the lock". However, in asking the question, they clearly were unable to do so, and seem to have stumbled upon the first figurative "key" purely by accident.

Comment: @Ben, sure. I just hate wasting puzzles by answering them. The whole point of this thing is to let a player figure it out on his own.

Comment: Normally, sure, I can agree with that, but that then defeats the entire purpose of this site! Haha

Answer (score 3):

To get the golem to move, you have to kill things near it.

To elaborate, these golems (found in multiple places throughout Drangleic Castle) only activate if they receive souls. To do this, you have to kill enemies near them, which will lead to them dropping souls, but if you are within range of the golem, the souls will go to *it*, rather than you.